# Keyboard not working after waking from suspend/sleep

Tags: keyboard, suspend

Just recently my Tomoko keyboard stopped working with Ubuntu 16.04.  It only happens after waking the PC from suspend.  The mouse works fine but the keyboard does not.  I have to unplug it and plug it back in before its starts working again.  Does anyone have any ideas how to trouble shoot this?  I looked in `dmesg` but not really sure what to look for.

I see this "failure" after plugging the Tomoko keyboard back in but unsure if its related to the hang after waking from suspend?  It also works despite this error (`hid-generic 0003:04D9:A0CD.000B: usb_submit_urb(ctrl) failed: -1`)

```
[ 9541.053188] usb 3-13: new full-speed USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd
[ 9541.190014] usb 3-13: New USB device found, idVendor=04d9, idProduct=a0cd
[ 9541.190021] usb 3-13: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[ 9541.190025] usb 3-13: Product: USB Keyboard
[ 9541.194898] input: USB Keyboard as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-13/3-13:1.0/0003:04D9:A0CD.000A/input/input32
[ 9541.249553] hid-generic 0003:04D9:A0CD.000A: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.11 Keyboard [USB Keyboard] on usb-0000:00:14.0-13/input0
[ 9546.059820] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eno1 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:2c:30:33:eb:46:1c:08:00 SRC=0.0.0.0 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=0 DF PROTO=2 
[ 9551.252501] hid-generic 0003:04D9:A0CD.000B: usb_submit_urb(ctrl) failed: -1
[ 9551.252519] hid-generic 0003:04D9:A0CD.000B: timeout initializing reports
```

The odd thing is after the PC is suspended I can use the Tomoko keyboard (tap space bar) to wake the PC, but after that the keyboard no longer works.  I have to unplug it and plug back in.

Looking in `dmesg` I believe this is what I get after trying to wake after suspend:

```
[10171.636787] hid-generic 0003:04D9:A0CD.000B: usb_submit_urb(ctrl) failed: -19
```

Comment: Mine does something very similar.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to fix the problem by adding `usbhid.quirks=0x04D9:0xA0CD:0x20000408` to kernel boot parameters as described here https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/280574/41667.

Comment: In my situation the problem caused by `xscreensaver`, Just remove this and enjoy.