# Keyboard stops working after unlocking the screen after systemctl suspend

Tags: 16.04, keyboard, suspend, xmonad

A problem goes as follows:

1. I start Ubuntu, login to xmonad.
2. I run `systemctl suspend`.
3. I wake the system pressing any key.
4. Unlock the screen by typing password (keyboard works here).
5. Ups... the keyboard is not responding, nothing.

The PC is running Ubuntu 16.04 with 4.4.0-103-generic kernel, has Xeon processor, I use Kinesis Advantage keyboard.

I can use mouse to copy&paste previously issued commands.

Important: it does not always happen.

Tried solutions / known similar:

- [Keyboard not working after suspend to ram (sleep)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38797/keyboard-not-working-after-suspend-to-ram-sleep) (does not work)
- [Keyboard not working after waking from suspend/sleep](https://askubuntu.com/questions/811162/keyboard-not-working-after-waking-from-suspend-sleep) (seems to not be related)
- [Keyboard stops working Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/772056/keyboard-stops-working-ubuntu-16-04) (here someone writing about kernel version and Kinesis Keyboard)

Comment: Did you manage to fix this?

Comment: No. No workable fix, but i found a workaround. Apparently, the keyboard wakes when I switch a window focus, e.g. leaving a gedit open next to terminal I move the mouse to gedit and the keyboard wakes up. Now, I always lock/suspend with a two windows sharing a workspace.